# How to Suppress warning in ScottPlot Win Form Application

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, scottplot

Since Visual Studio has removed the Charts from the tool box I was using this [Scottplot](https://github.com/ScottPlot/ScottPlot/issues/1264) library. Its very pretty and neat except that it reminds painfully to developer to call refresh method after adding the data in the plot.

[image]

Is there a way to suppress it?

Cant find anything [here](https://github.com/ScottPlot/ScottPlot/issues/1264) as well

Thanks

Comment: You can use `yourFormsPlot.Configuration.WarnIfRenderNotCalledManually = false`

However, as a developer on ScottPlot, this is a very poor idea. You should not suppress this warning but comply with it. You need to call Refresh() after modifying the plot, it will only automatically update in select circumstances which are not easy to predict (I believe it goes back to preserving behaviour from v3 or even earlier)